# Display a SPFx web part within a popup on a modern page

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts

I am looking for a way to display an SPFx web part within a pop-window in a way, similar to using the modal window ( as descrbed here: https://www.ericgregorich.com/blog/2013/12/30/open-a-page-in-a-sharepoint-modal-window ), but within a modern page.

More or less the same question seems to have been asked already:

https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/issues/177

[Is there any alternative of model-dialog available for SharePoint Modern Page?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/228098/is-there-any-alternative-of-model-dialog-available-for-sharepoint-modern-page?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

[Add an SPFx WebPart from an SPFx Extension on a modern site](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/240244/add-an-spfx-webpart-from-an-spfx-extension-on-a-modern-site)

, but the answers are far from satisfactory.

I mean, putting a whole web part, containing many additional components and dependencies within an Office UI Fabric Dialog is a way too inconvenient for many projects.

There must be better ways to achieve that.
Is using the Office UI Fabric Dialog really the only option currently available?

Answer (score 1):

Office UI-fabric is tailored specifically for Office 365 and SharePoint Online. Even if you find another front-end framework that works, you should not expect it to continue working in the future, as SharePoint Online is a product that changes constantly over time.

If you use a framework for your webpart (React / Angular) it's perfectly acceptable and quite simple to put the entire program logic within a modal dialog.

To answer your question: Yes, if I were you, I would consider it my only option and the natural choice.

Answer (score 1):

Use the pnp-SPFX-Controls for open page in popup as similar to classic

https://sharepoint.github.io/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/controls/IFrameDialog/